# HTML Text Field Input ID and utilization

Tags: html, variables, field

I have a text box

```
 <p> <input type="text" name="name1" id="usethisid" maxlength="100" value=" <p>
```

Whatever text is in that field is then the ID right? When i tried taking usethisid and putting it elsewhere just to display whatever the user typed didn't work.

Simply, user should enter something in text field press ok button and then the ID should be saved to whatever user wrote so i can use that ID to display anywhere on the site.

Using PHP $_POST in this code - name1 is not displayed

```
              <ul class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item">
                        <span class="badge">1549pts</span>
                            $_POST["name1"]; //name1should be displayed
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The id attribute in an HTML tag is used to identify the tag in a more general manner, whereas the **name** attribute is used to process requests (get and post for example)

Depending on how are you processing your form you can use either of them.

For example if you want to retrieve the content of your text input using javascript you can use

```
document.getElementById("usethisid").value
```

I made [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/guilhermesena/5meu8s2j/) to exemplify.

However if you are using a PHP form submission you'll want to use the name attribute instead of id, and the content of your input can be retrieved by doing: $_POST["name1"];

In PHP you can try this:

In your HTML file, try the following:

```
<p> 
    <form method="post" action="something.php">
        <input type="text" name="name1" id="usethisid" maxlength="100" value="some default text />
        <input type="submit" value="send!" />
    </form>
</p>
```

Then make a php file called "something.php" (noticed that I referenced it in the form tag) with the following line:

```
echo($_POST['name1']);
```

This should display whatever was written in the text input.

By the way whenever you want to print a PHP variable name in HTML the correct syntax is

```
<?php echo($your_variable_name); ?>
```

instead of just writing $your_variable_name as is, otherwise HTML will just interpret it as a text.

Comment: Very helpful! I used $_POST["name1"]; but $_POST["name1"]; was displayed as is. I'm using PHP and HTML.

Comment: Just edited my post. Let me know if this clarifies how to access input form contents. It's a little more complicated than just printing the variable name in your HTML.